# torchvision version issue when installing mmf

Tags: python, anaconda, torch, torchvision

I'm trying to install Facebook's [mmf](https://github.com/facebookresearch/mmf) to replicate benchmarks from the ML competition [Hateful Memes](https://ai.facebook.com/blog/hateful-memes-challenge-and-data-set/).
I'm following the Getting Started documentation [here](https://mmf.sh/docs/).

This is what I get:

```
(gpu) C:\Users\abc>pip install --upgrade --pre mmf
Collecting mmf
  Using cached mmf-1.0.0rc10.tar.gz (160 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torchvision==0.6.0 (from mmf) (from versions: 0.1.6, 0.1.7, 0.1.8, 0.1.9, 0.2.0, 0.2.1, 0.2.2, 0.2.2.post2, 0.2.2.post3, 0.3.0, 0.4.1, 0.5.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torchvision==0.6.0 (from mmf)
    ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torchvision==0.6.0 (from mmf) (from versions: 0.1.6, 0.1.7, 0.1.8, 0.1.9, 0.2.0, 0.2.1, 0.2.2, 0.2.2.post2, 0.2.2.post3, 0.3.0, 0.4.1, 0.5.0)
    ERROR: No matching distribution found for torchvision==0.6.0 (from mmf)
```

If I check my installed conda packages I can find:

```
torch                     1.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
torchvision               0.6.1                    pypi_0    pypi
```

Comment: i am also facing same issue is it resolved ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one workaround:

#### 1. Install specified versions of 'torch' and 'torchvision', before installing mmf (otherwise causes the issue shown above)

`pip install torch==1.5.0 torchvision==0.6.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html`

---

Instead of installing mmf from pip, one can fork the repository to get brand-new features. But running `git clone https://github.com/facebookresearch/mmf.git` also causes [an issue](https://github.com/facebookresearch/mmf/issues/369).

---

#### 2.  Run the following to fork mmf from source & change directory:

`git clone --config core.symlinks=true https://github.com/facebookresearch/mmf.git`

`cd mmf`

#### 3. Install mmf:

`pip install --editable .`

#### 4. [OPTINAL] Run tests:

`pytest ./tests/`